# Reading SymlinkTextInputFormat with Spark

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, pyspark

AWS S3 Inventory will output a file called `symlinks.txt`

`symlinks.txt` is an implementation of [SymlinkTextInputFormat](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r3.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/SymlinkTextInputFormat.html)

There's documentation on [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) and [Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/09/03/transform-your-aws-data-lake-using-databricks-delta-and-aws-glue-data-catalog-service.html) on how to read these files into Athena, with mentions about the fact it should be possible with Spark but I'm unable to confirm this is working .

- What would be a proper way to read symlink format in spark.
- What should be the format of the file for spark to be able to see the
  files?

Comment: In my opinion, Symlinks are actually links to the same inode table(hardware location) which you should read just you read a normal file and not bother about being a symlink. Please share your error if you get any.

Comment: @Sampath not so, the name might be somewhat confusing. SymlinkTextInputFormat takes the approach of UNIX inode pointers and applies it as a big data concept. Once is acting at a file system level, mostly on local disk level while SymlinkTextInputFormat implements a data pointer into a distributed file system, that is (generally speaking) being offered using an API exposed at the network layer.

Comment: @MaximVeksler were you able to read this table from spark? also is it readable from hive cli ?

Comment: @RamSinha yes I was, but I no longer participate in SO community due to their previous actions (https://twitter.com/mvxlr/status/1184541607816765447). Please feel free to write to me at maxim@vekslers.org where I would be glad to share my solution.

Comment: @MaximVeksler I want to contact you, but I am not sure about your pronouns.